# How to extract URL of Facebook image

Tags: python, php, selenium, beautifulsoup

Given a FB url like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid[LONGUSERID]&set=a.313002535549859&type=3&theater
```

How could I extract the real photo URL using PHP or Python?

Normally the actual URL looks like this ( as seen in Chrome Network tab)

```
https://scontent.fbru1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-1/cp0/p32x32/11942095_139657766378816_623531952343456734_o.jpg?_nc_cat=106&_nc_sid=0081f9&_nc_ohc=VpijQtyWbUQAX-fsPMj&_nc_ht=scontent.fbru1-1.fna&oh=eb4435eed183716c807b405d0d57c3a4&oe=5F674BAB
```

But is there a way to automate this extraction this with script? Any example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest example.
I just got an HTML page, divided the text by double quotes into lines. Then I checked to see if the JPG extension was on the line.

```py
import requests
from html import unescape
from urllib.parse import unquote

url = "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=445552432123146"

response = requests.get(url)
if response:
    lines = response.text.split('\"')
    for line in lines:
        if ".jpg" in line:
            print(unquote(unescape(line)))
else:
    print("fail!")
```

With the help of Selenium you can already search for elements in HTML code correctly.

Comment: Your example works but when I put in another BID url, the Response comes back with 404 in it. The photo can be opened in browser though.